# Firebase-Tools: Initialize project using the CLI as a module

Tags: firebase-tools

I am working on a vscode extension which integrates firebase-tools into vscode commands. In order to do this I need to run the firebase-tools cli commands as a functions through a module which is said to be possible at the bottom of the [github repo readme](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

I am trying to initialise a firebase project through running the a similar function to what is written for deploy but written for `init` and I am getting the error that `Cannot read property 'cwd' of undefined` even through the value I am giving for cwd is defined.

I have looked at the source for the functions but it is quite obfuscated and is not picked up in IntelliSense.

Is there official documentation as to how to use the node package as a module? And more specifically the `init` function as well as giving features to use?